# PostgreSQL: Find shared beginning of string with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

How can I determine the shared beginning of two or more strings using SQL?

For example, say I have 3 URIs:

```
'http://www.example.com/service/1'
'http://www.example.com/service/2'
'http://www.example.com/service/3'
```

How can I determine they all share `'http:://www.example.com/service/'` using SQL?

Comment: You can try to create a custom aggregate for that.

Comment: Lots has been written about this; search for "longest common substring".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create an aggregate function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createaggregate.html)

```
create or replace function string_common_start (s text, t text)
returns text as $$
declare
    sa char(1)[] = string_to_array(s, null);
    ta char(1)[] = string_to_array(t, null);
    output_s text = '';
begin

    if s = t or t = '' or s = ''
    then return t;
    end if;

    for i in 1 .. least(length(s), length(t)) loop
        if sa[i] = ta[i]
        then
            output_s = output_s || sa[i];
        else
            exit;
        end if;
    end loop;

    return output_s;

end; $$ language plpgsql strict;

create aggregate string_common_start (text) (
    sfunc = string_common_start,
    stype = text
);
```

It will not aggregate null values

```
select string_common_start(s)
from (values
    ('http://www.example.com/service/1'),
    ('http://www.example.com/service/2'),
    ('http://www.example.com/service/3'),
    (null)
) s(s);
       string_common_start       
---------------------------------
 http://www.example.com/service/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LIKE keyword in your query. As such for instance:

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column LIKE '[String to match]%'
```

you just have to know/enter the string you're trying to match. In your case:

```
'http:://www.example.com/service/'
```